# How to trigger change event after select new added option from select tag using select2 in angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-select2

#### How to trigger change event after select new added option from select tag using select2 in angularjs ?

I have created directive of angular js to apply select2 in `<select>` tag.  I want to trigger change event after `select2` apply on the element. I am using tagging of select2. After adding the new tag in select, I want to trigger change event.  But `ng-change` event trigger first after that `select2:select` event trigger. So I am not able to get the value of `ng-model` after selecting the newly added option.  Please help me to resolve this issue.

I have used **jquery 3.2.1**, **select2 4.0.2**, **angular js 1.7.8**.

I have tried with this below code :

```
<select custom-select2 id="items" ng-model="items" class="form-control"
        ng-change="onChange(items)">
    <option ng-repeat="item in itemlist" value="{{ item.id }}">
      {{ item.name }}
    </option>   
</select>
```

```
 let app= angular.module("app",[]);
 app.controller('itemAddController',function($scope, $http){
    $scope.itemlist= {};      
    $scope.onChange = (items) => {
      console.log(items)
    }     
 });
```

```
app.directive('customSelect2', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
            $timeout( function(){
                element.select2({
                    allowClear:true,
                    tags: true,
                    tokenSeparators: [",",";"],
                    createTag: function (params) {
                        let obj = {};
                        let term = $.trim(params.term);
                        if (term === '') {
                            return null;
                        }
                        obj = {
                          id: term,
                          text: term,
                          newTag: true // add additional parameters
                        };
                        return obj;
                    }
                }).on("select2:select", function(e) {
                    if(e.params.data.newTag){
                        scope.itemlist.push(e.params.data.text)
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(e.params.data.text);
                    }
                });
            },200);

        }
    }
});
```

I want to call function onChange after select2 event trigger.

Comment: Is the `$timeout` necessary? Or did you add it in an attempt to get it to work?

Comment: **$timeout**  is necessary. Because I have set placeholder dynamically on the select dropdown. And this placeholder text comes from language file for multilingual text which is called on page load after that attribute directives render with select2.